# How do I tell whether a question is protected?

Tags: support, search

I tried searching for isprotected:yes and is:protected to no avail.

Comment: What is your goal? There is a banner that is at the top of questions that are protected. Are you trying to search for protected questions or just know when they are protected?

Comment: See the MSE question [Can we have a “isprotected” search operator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52825). In short: There is no operator that does that.

Comment: @JoeW I am just curious.  I noticed at 10 rep. we gain(ed) the "answer protected questions" privilege.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protected questions like [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/7509065) will have a banner, either at the bottom by the new answer box, or at the top, that indicates their protection status. There's not a way to search for them though.

Comment: I see no banner at the top of that question. :/

Comment: @greg-tumolo I just checked while logged out and it was on the bottom then. Check there too.

Comment: This banner shows up only if you have less than 10 or more than 15k rep.

Comment: @pppery Is that new? Because I definitely used to see it while I was in between.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339709/566903

Comment: You can search for those in SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1262687

Comment: @rene That should be a separate answer.

Comment: @pppery meh, I think it can fit nicely in this answer.